# TypeORM How to create relation between three entities

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm struggling on how it would be best to connect three entities together.
So I have three entities: User, Medal and Ingredient

I want that when a User wins a medal it would also indicate for which ingredients he won the medal. So eventually I think it should form a table like so:

**user_id, medal_id, ingerdient_ids**

I have tried to have this under Medal:

```
@ManyToMany(() => Ingredient, ingredient => ingredient.id)
@JoinTable()
ingredient: ingredient[];

@ManyToMany(() => User, user => user.medals)
@JoinTable()
users: User[];
```

and this under User:

```
@ManyToMany(() => Medal, medal => medal.users)
@JoinColumn()
medals: Medal[];
```

It did create a medal_id - user_id and a medal_id - component_id, but it didn't create the desired relation between the three